# AWS CLI - Retrieve Parsed Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there any way, using the AWS CLI, to retrieve the parsed credentials the CLI will be using? I need to use these credentials in a different script to connect to S3. There are a few steps to determine which credentials should be used, as documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html but I would like to not have to parse that myself and just let the AWS CLI do it as well.

Comment: Have you considered something like http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html or http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html ?

Comment: You could maybe read the underlying boto source code to see if there's some way to retrieve either the credential provider or the credentials themselves directly.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code in AWS on a server that had an assigned role with desired permissions ended up solving the issue for me temporarily. Curious what others may come up with though.